# Converting bytes to string with str() returns string with speech marks

Tags: python, string, byte, interpreter

Say I have a variable containing bytes:

```
>>> a = b'Hello World'
```

It can be verified with:

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Now I try and convert a into a string with `str()`:

```
>>> b = str(a)
```

and sure enough it is a string:

```
>>> type(b)
<class 'str'>
```

Now I try and print `b` but I get a totally unexpected result:

```
>>> print(b)
b'Hello World'
```

It returns a string, as I would expect but also it keeps the `b` (byte symbol) and the `'` (quotation marks).

Why does it do this, and not just print the message between the quotation marks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of a `bytes` value as a string in some default 8-bit encoding. It's just binary data. As such, `str(a)` returns an encoding-agnostic string to represent the value of the byte string. If you want `'Hello World'`, be specific and decode the value.

```
>>> b = a.decode()
>>> type(b)
>>> str
>>> print(b)
Hello World
```

In Python 2, the distinction between bytes and text was blurred. Python 3 went to great lengths to separate the two: `bytes` for binary data, and `str` for readable text.

For another perspective, compare

```
>>> list("Hello")
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

with

```
>>> list(b"Hello")
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Answer (score 3):

What `str(b)` does here is convert bytes to a string by trying to call `thing.__str__`, which fails because bytes have no `__str__` and then falling back to `__repr__`, which returns the string required to create this object in the repl.

If you think about it, just converting `bytes` to a `str` makes little sense, as you need to know the encoding. You can use `bytes.decode(encoding)` to convert `bytes` to `str` properly.

```
b.decode("utf-8")
```

The encoding can also be left empty, in which case a default (likely utf-8) will be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

`str` usually transforms an object into a string that represents it. There is no better representation than b'contains' of a bytes object. You probably want to use `decode`, where you also specify encoding of the bytes object, that should be used when transforming to string

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, when you type-cast byte string using `str(s)`, it creates a new string as `b'Hello World'` *(keeping the `"b"` denoting byte string at the start)*. It is because byte-string doesn't have a `__str__` function defined. Hence, it makes the call to `__repr__` which returns the same string which byte used for the representation of it's object values (i.e string preceded by "b"). For example:

```
>>> a = b'Hello World'
>>> str(a)
"b'Hello World'"
```

There are two ways to convert byte-like object to string. For example:

1. **Decode byte-string to string**: You can `decode` your byte-string `a` to string as:

   ```
   >>> a.decode()
   'Hello World'
   ```
2. **Convert byte-string  to `utf-8` string** as:

   ```
   >>> str(a, 'utf-8')
   'Hello World'
   ```

Comment: @Simon `a = b'r'\xb9\xfe''` doesn't looks like a right syntax to me after your edit

Comment: Indeed.  I made a stupid oversight.  I've edited it back.

Comment: how can i convert "b'Hello World'" to "Hello World"